Any way to deal with 2FA with PyPi without a phone?
I've just created a PyPi account, because I'm trying to understand "best practice" for Python library modules, and am following this.
At this point it tells me that I need to have a PyPi account. But, after signing up I'm finding I'm absolutely required to enabled 2-factor authentication (2FA).
In my opinion it would be extremely silly for me to have to use my phone for this purpose, given that I'll always be sitting at a computer when I want to log in. And also bearing in mind that I don't anticipate having anything there which is so valuable that it needs that level (2FA) of security. So:

any way of just managing PyPi without 2FA (this doesn't seem possible), or...

any computer-based application (W10) which I can use to enable 2FA? PyPi gives you a page listing 5 or 6 "TOTP authentication applications". But they all seem to be apps for phones only, not for computers.



There are dozens of TOTP applications that run on desktops. Software recommendations are out of scope.

@Ramhound Unfortunately my experience of 2FA to date has been limited to most people's: I point my phone at a QR code and some magic happens. I have in fact already examined/installed about 10 TOTP/2FA apps which you can install on a W10 machine. But exactly what you're meant to DO (with a 30-character code provided by PyPi) is totally baffling. None of these apps come with adequate how-tos and I'm completely in the dark at this stage. I can't think of a better place, or any place in fact, to ask for help than here.

The character code is the secret code. You copy and paste it into the 2FA application. Sounds like you need to understand how TOTP 2FA works to better understand any application you find works.


any computer-based application (W10) which I can use to enable 2FA?

The hotpie package in PyPi is a ~10-line implementation of the OATH TOTP algorithm. Give it the current timestamp and the Base32-decoded secret key from the QR code (use pyqrcode or pyzbar if the website lacks an option to show the key as text), and it will print the appropriate OTP.

Anyone struggling with this or similar issues and having the same constraints as myself might be interested in the fruits of my labours. It took me about 2 hours to find a solution: this might shorten that time.
My requirements were:

TOTP/2FA app on a desktop/laptop (W10), NOT a phone
absolutely no money to be paid by me at any stage either now or in the future
simple and obvious thing you have to do with the 30-character code (presented as an alternative to the QR code on the PyPi page)
(highly desirable) choice of installation location, to avoid more bloat on my C: drive in particular

On point 2, annoyingly but unsurprisingly, I found that more than one app presented itself as "free", but wanted me to pay something for the immense privilege of generating and using TOTPs. Name no names, but "usual suspects".
Other apps proved defective: one app, keepassxc, installed... but then didn't run at all. Even when I tried to run the .exe file from the command line.
I finally found a simple app which just worked: free-authenticator aka verifyr. For all I know this could be dodgy as hell and currently eating up my hard drive as I speak. Worse: compromising my PyPi account's security: how tragic that would be. Scamadviser reckons it's OK.
On running the app for the first time I was asked to create a password.
I then pressed a "+" button in the bottom right. Above this appeared a box with the words "Enter a setup key". I entered the 30-character code from PyPi. And then maybe pressed. And maybe entered some details like "name of issuer" ("PyPi").
After that I was able to click a refresh button which generated a 6-figure number. I entered that in the location at PyPi. Worked!
The second time I ran the app that "PyPi" account (or whatever) was there already. Does that mean I can generate TOTPs at will? Logging out and back in again at PyPi suggests ...yes!

Ente Auth is free. Free as in air. It's even open source.

I tried Ente Auth as one of the first attempts. It proved highly defective as an application and it was in no way obvious what you're meant to do to set things up or enter the secret code. It had me totally tearing out what's left of my hair. YMMV.

Perhaps I don't understand how you found it defective.  Press the + symbol, paste the secret code into the field, and hit save. If Authy works on a phone, then I am 1000% sure Ente Auth would work since I recently transitioned every single one of my TOTP authenticators to it.
